# Мерцает textView при обновлении с помощью rxJava

Tags: java, android, textview, rxjava

Есть фрагмет с таким кодом

```
 StringObservable.from(inputStream)
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(String::new)
                .map(s-> {
                    Log.d("rx", s);
                    return s;
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(textView::setText);
```

в inputStream приходит массив байт два раза в секунду, и по задумке textView тоже должен обновляться два раза в секунду, и текст не должен исчезать, но текст то пропадает то появляется. По логам видно что строка не пустая.
вот [видео](https://radikal.ru/video/tD9kesQMsWK) неправильной работы.

Если использовать handler то все работает как нужно, но хотелось бы разобраться с rxJava.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему текст может исчезать?

Comment: Видео не смотрел, однако могу предложить попробовать подписываться не на главном потоке, а уж текст выводить на главном: `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Comment: Поправил. К сожалению без изменений.

Comment: Странно. Других идей у меня нет. Возможно, они бы появились при просмотре видео, но неизвестный файл с файлообменника я качать не буду.

Comment: Его можно прямо из браузера смотреть)

Comment: Я не доверяю этому сайту. К тому же мне подозрительным кажется попытка выкладывать видео не на YouTube, т.к. он всё ещё не забанен и на нём можно относительно безопасно видео смотреть.

Comment: А что в логах в этот момент когда пустота появляется? есть ли какая закономерность? может у вас одна строчка а текст в две строчки?
PS вот так логи плохо выводить используйте  doOnNext()

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, проблема была в том что в строке был перенос \n.